# How do I get a list of nearby *residences* using Google Maps API and a latitude/longitude pair?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I want to allow users of my web-app to select addresses from a list that are near a specific latitude/longitude pair.

The kicker is that I need ***residential*** addresses.  The Google Maps "Places" API can do what I want, but it won't show ***residences***.

How can I get a list of ***residences*** in a reverse geocoding request?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for a source of residential address info, it would vary widely between countries, and within the US, between states and counties. Majority (but not all) of counties in the US maintain the so called "public records" in the office of county tax assessor. There are also several aggregators who collect and resell this data in electronic format. However, this type of data is very expensive, in the thousands of $$.